# TYPO3 Custom Content Element with repeatable fieldsets or '+ Content' Button

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

So, I'm new to TYPO3. I worked myself through some guides and documentations to be able to create custom content elements on my own.

Now, for one of my desired content elements, I need to have a set of fields I want to be able to make repeatable, since I want to leave the choice up to the editor, how many of the sets he wants to add.

I'm running on TYPO3 version 7.6

I have already seen both options in existing content elements:

1. Content elements that work like a wrapper where you can add additional content elements within and
2. Content elements where you can add fieldsets within its configuration.

I'm searching for examples or written guides to recreate this, since I can't figure it out from the source code of those examples I've seen.

Edit(27.12.16):

So after seeing a few reactions and replies, I want to further clarify what I'm looking for.

I do NOT need an assistant plugin to create new content elements, I'm already past that.

Let me draw an example, to better describe what I want to achieve.

I do already have a working Content Element.
I have defined a set of fields (for example name & phone) shown in the TYPO3 backend. Now I want to leave the choice to the editor, if he just wants one set of 'name & phone' fields, or 2, or 8.
Therefore I want to create a '+'-button or something like that, for the editor to click on to make a new input set of 'name & phone'-inputs.

Comment: Which examples did you seen? Maybe extension dce by Armin Ruediger Vieweg already meet your needs.

Comment: @jokumer good to know, thanks for the reference. I'd like to avoid installing further extensions, but maybe the source code of this plugin helps me get it done.
I saw a few examples within the t3bootstrap plugin.

Comment: Here is all examples https://github.com/bootstraptheme-for-typo3/fluidbootstraptheme what you need for TYPO3 7.6 and be sure all code clear for reuse. Fill free ask future question here i will try explain in Details

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension called [mask](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/mask/), with that you can simply click together your own content element with many different kinds of relations and fields.

Then there is a second extension [mask_export](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/mask_export) that exports your new content elements into an own extension.

With those you can just create a very basic content element

- export it
- see what code was generated
- add more to your content element
- export it
- check the code

  and so on :-)